# MPI Op_create and reduce to make a vector that contains updates from all processes

Tags: c, mpi

I have a program I'm trying to make parallel using MPI. In this program I have a duplicate of vector on each process. The individual process can edit any of the items in the vector but by design none of the items will be edited on more than one process. I then need a way to update the vector across the processes so each process once more contains a duplicate where the vector contains the updated values from each process.

I can think of a few potential ways to do this including using an additional bool vector for changed or not, a gather then comparison then broadcast, but my favourite involves using a allreduce call with a custom MPI_Op to compare the values and change to the unique value. Unfortunately it seems MPI_op is defined such that only two vectors are passed to in preventing me from finding the unique value.

I imagine this type of problem is not especially uncommon so please feel free to point out an alternative approach I may have missed.
Thanks.

This is what I was trying but as you can tell this fails as it can incorrectly update the unique value instead of the correct one.

```
void assignDifferent(double *in, double * inout, int *len, MPI_Datatype *dptr){
int i;
double newValue;
for (i = 0; i<*len ; i++){
 *inout = in[i]==*inout? *in:*inout;
 in++,inout++;
}
}
```